# Find and extract file from Git stash

Tags: git

Maybe I'm using git stash too often, but that's what I usually do when I want to throw away my experiments in the project.

Question 1:

- How could I search for a filename in all my current stashes?

Question 2:

- How could I extract this file to separate folder?
- or another option: How to launch visual diff tool for that stashed file?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555410/is-it-possible-to-search-through-git-stash-items for an answer to Question 1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A little more to the point would be to recognize that `refs/stash` is reflog of a a pseudo-branch (ref):

```
git rev-list --walk-reflogs stash # (long option)
git rev-list -g stash # (short option)
```

So you could locate the file:

```
for sha in $(git rev-list -g stash); 
do 
     git ls-tree -r $sha:; 
done |
   grep "$SOMEFILENAME" | 
   sort --unique
```

(The unique sort is to remove duplicates of the same version in different stashes).

E.g.:

```
$ for sha in $(git rev-list -g stash); do git ls-tree -r $sha:; done | grep numeric.js | sort -u
100644 blob f1c9a61910ae1bbd562615444a45688b93e9d808    LSPO.Web/DaVinci/JScript/numeric.js
```

So you can launch a visual diff using e.g.

```
kompare numeric.js <(git cat-file -p f1c9a61910ae1bbd562615444a45688b93e9d808)
```

Of course, if you already had a hunch which reflog contained the different file, this would be much easier:

```
git diff stash@{3} -- numeric.js
```

Comment: But how to extract the stashed file to separate folder? I think this is important for binary stashed file, since we cannot view the diff for binary in a stash.

Answer (score 8):

The answer from @sehe gives a great answer for Question 2.

I came to this page looking for a better answer to Question 1 than what I currently use. What I currently use is a shell script `stashshowall.sh` and then I grep the output.

The difference of my answer is that while the other answers here tell you whether the file that you are looking for was changed, they don't tell you which stash the file is in in case you want to `apply` that stash.

My answer is purely using "porcelain" git commands, but it works for me.

```
#!/bin/sh
#  stashshowall.sh
for stash in `git stash list | sed 's/\(\w*\)\:.*/\1/'`
do
    echo
    echo "$stash"
    git stash show $stash
done
```

So to answer Question 1, I run

```
> stashshowall.sh | grep "stash\|some-file"
```

which gives me

```
stash@{0}
stash@{1}
 .../some-dir/some-file     | 16 ++--
stash@{2}
stash@{3}
stash@{4}
 .../some-dir/some-file     | 2 ++--
stash@{5}
```

This way I know that I need to `apply` or look further at `stash{1}` or `stash{4}`

Comment: If someone wants to run on windows from git bash: `$ sh stashshowall.sh | grep "stash\|your_file"`

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr**

grep stash for filename:

```
git reflog stash -- '*fileglob*'
git log -g stash -- '*fileglob*'
```

grep stash for content:

```
git stash list -G<regex>
```

---

### Search stash entry for filename

From [git help stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> The latest stash you created is stored in `refs/stash`; older stashes are found in the reflog of this reference and can be named using the usual reflog syntax (e.g. `stash@{0}` ...)

From [git help reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog):

> `git reflog show` is an alias for `git log -g --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline`

From [git help log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--g):

> **-g**
> **--walk-reflogs**
> Instead of walking the commit ancestry chain, walk reflog entries from the most recent one to older ones.

[git log synopsis](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log [<options>] [<revision range>] [[\--] <path>...]
```

From the [git revisions specifications](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem):

> **`<refname>`, e.g. master, heads/master, refs/heads/master**
> A symbolic ref name. ...
> When ambiguous, a `<refname>` is disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules:
>
> 1. If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
> 2. otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;

Now we have everything together:

```
git reflog stash -- '*fileglob*'
git log -g stash -- '*fileglob*'
```

So we `stash` will resolve to `refs/stash`, and `-g` will cause the entire branch to be walked, and `-- '*fileglob*' will match any paths in that commit.

### Search stash for content

[git help stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-listltoptionsgt):

> ... The command takes options applicable to the *git log* command to control what is shown and how. See [git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

From [git help log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--Gltregexgt):

> **-G`<regex>`**
> Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines that match `<regex>`.

So the easy command is:

```
git stash list -G<regex>
```

Other pickaxe commands should work as well.

Answer (score 3):

I use this to search for a file among stashes

`git stash list | cut -d ":" -f 1 | xargs -L1 git diff --stat | grep <filename>`

You can create a new branch that contains the stash (`git checkout -b <new_branch> <stash>`) and then copy the file wherever and later merge it back.

You can use `git difftool` to get a visual of your diff.

EDIT: To get the commit of the stash along with the filename, you can use this shell script:

```
for i in $(git stash list | cut -d ":" -f 1 | xargs -L1 git show | grep commit |
  cut -d" " -f 2)
do
  if git show $i --oneline --stat | grep ht.h 
  then
    echo $i
  fi
done
```

It will print the commit under the filename.

Comment: This gave me just the file name and number of deletions/additions which is kinda useless.

Comment: Check my edit if you want to know the commit as well.